# Using SQL Server Export Wizard in batches

Tags: sql-server, database-migration

I'm using SQL Server Export Wizard to migrate 2 million rows over to a Postgres database. After 10 hours, I got to 1.5 million records and it quit. Argh.

So I'm thinking the safest way to get this done is to do it in batches. 100k rows at a time. But how do you do that?

Conceptually, I'm thinking:

```
SELECT * FROM invoices WHERE RowNum BETWEEN 300001 AND 400000
```

But RowNum doesn't exist, right? Do I need to create a new column and somehow get a +1 incremental ID in there that I can use in a statement like this? There is no primary key and there are no columns with unique values.

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to do it in batches, yes.  You'll need that primary key :)  I would say add an IDENTITY column on your table, then make it your primary key.

Comment: PostgreSQL is not SQL Server, so I've removed that tag. Please use only the tags that are actually applicable to your question.

Comment: @KenWhite Destination table is in Postgres

Comment: But your question is about SQL Server, not PostgreSQL, and using SQL Server batches has nothing to do with PostgreSQL.

Comment: Not my question, but meh...  It could be both IMHO.  But yes, from the angle taken it is primarily a SQL Server question.

Comment: Thanks @KenWhite. I wasn't sure if the destination platform had any implications for the solution at the source platform.

Answer (score 0):

The rows are invoices, so I created a new variable 'Quartile' that divides the invoice dollar values into quartiles using:

```
 SELECT *, 
    NTILE(4) OVER(ORDER BY TOTAL_USD) AS QUARTILE
    INTO invoices2
    FROM invoices
```

This created four groups of 500k rows each. Then in the export wizard, I asked to:

```
SELECT * FROM invoices2 WHERE QUARTILE = 1 -- (or 2, 3, 4 etc)
```

And I'm going to send each group of 500k rows to its own Postgres table and then merge them over on pgAdmin. That way, if any one crashes, I can just do that smaller grouping over again without affecting the integrity of the others. Does that make sense? Maybe would have been just as easy to create an incrementing primary key?

**Update:**

All four batches transferred successfully. Worth noting that the total transfer time was 4x faster when sending the 2M rows as four simultaneous batches of 500k--4 hours instead of 16! Combined them back into a single table using the following query in pgAdmin:

```
--Combine tables back into one, total row count matches original 
SELECT * INTO invoices_all FROM (
  SELECT * FROM quar1
  UNION All
  SELECT * FROM quar2
  UNION All
  SELECT * FROM quar3
  UNION All
  SELECT * FROM quar4
) as tmp
```

And checked sums of all variables that had to be converted from SQL Server "money" to Postgres "numeric"

```
--All numeric sums match those from original
SELECT SUM("TOTAL_BEFORE_TP_TAX")
      ,SUM("TP_SELLER")
      ,SUM("TOTAL_BEFORE_TAX")
      ,SUM("TAX_TOTAL")
      ,SUM("TOTAL")
      ,SUM("TOTAL_BEFORE_TP_TAX_USD")
      ,SUM("TP_SELLER_USD")
      ,SUM("TOTAL_BEFORE_TAX_USD")
      ,SUM("TAX_TOTAL_USD")
      ,SUM("TOTAL_USD")
FROM PUBLIC.invoices_all
```

Comment: Can you guarantee that no new rows will be added between a failure and the repair? Because if you can't then partition might move. I would be pretty cautious about using a value which could change.

Comment: Thanks @Dale K, yes—in this case, it’s a static/closed database that only I have access to while this stuff is going on.

Comment: You should still have some sort of post-migration validation logic to know that what you thought was transferred was correct. Things like rowcounts are basic checks. More complicated ones are totals of numeric columns at different levels - customer, store, month, year, etc. If using floating point numbers you will need to account for the imprecision inherent in that datatype.

Comment: Thanks @Smor, copy that. Numeric column totals in addition to the row counts. Dollar amounts were in SQL Server’s “money” format and so were converted to Postgres “numeric”. I’ll need to check if that was problematic, especially for foreign currencies. Fortunately, all of the foreign currencies come with US dollar equivalents in the same table so all should be ok so long as those US $ values translated ok.